# Using smalot/pdfparser. I can extract text, but cannot extract form field data

Tags: php, parsing, pdf

I created a simple `pdf` using `InDesign` and can extract the text from my `pdf` using `smalot/pdfparser` code. The content within the pdf form fields does not get extracted though. Would parseContent or getContent work? If so, how is that configured? I have tried numerous ways and have gone through the `API` documentation, but I can't make sense of it.

```
include('pdfparser/vendor/autoload.php');
$parser = new \Smalot\Pdfparser\Parser();
$pdf = parser->parseFile('simple.pdf');
$text = $pdf->getText();
echo $text;
```

I've successfully used `getDetails`, but can't figure out `parseContent` or getContent - if they are even the correct solution for extracting the form field data that was entered and saved.

I cannot use a third party external program for this solution. Running `IIS` and using `PHP` only.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Learn [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you do so. When asking a question, be [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and be sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry about my vague question earlier. Hopefully my updates have brought it up to par.